# Detect if variable is undefined in list

Tags: javascript

Just learning JS an in writing a function and testing it to add a todo and display it we noticed the function worked fine when we actually entered a new todo such as:

addTodo('do something')

This added "do something" as expected to the end of the lost of todos.

When we mistakenly only entered the the function without anything in the brackets we noticed an "
undefined" element in our todo list was added. It looked like this:
["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "do something", **undefined**]

Being proactive and wanting to avoid needlessly adding undefined into a list we decided we would go off course and add some error handling or at least an if statement to at least send us a reminder that we need to enter a value in the brackets. This is where we started getting stumped.

So far in the if statement this is what we have and this is where we've been stumped.

How would we correctly use an if statement in this situation?

```
if (typeof addTodo === "undefined") 
{console.log('you need to add a todo sir!');} 
else { 
function addTodo(newTodo) 
{ todos.push(newTodo); console.log(todos); }}
```

Comment: I often just use `if (!addTodo) { console.log("please add a to do"}`. This will check for `null`, `undefined` and `""`. Your code is checking for a string containing the word `"undefined"` but the array contains the actual value `undefined`.

Comment: @Kokodoko `undefined` is a valid JavaScript data type, so `typeof x === 'undefined'` will evaluate to true for x set to undefined.

Comment: I know, but why the quotes around ‘undefined’ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function irrespective of the value passed where your function can be:

```
function addTodo(newTodo) {
   if (typeof newTodo === "undefined"){
      console.log("you need to add a todo sir!");
   } else {
      todos.push(newTodo);
      console.log(todos);
   }
}
```

Comment: ... and why not just accepting a ***non empty string value***, since most likely this was the definition of a valid todo-item?

Comment: Thank you. I was staring at it for too long. Below is our final code for this:
function addTodo(newTodo) {
if (typeof newTodo === "undefined"){ // see how it says 'typeof newTodo' instead of addTodo
console.log("Whoops! You didnt type anything in the brackets!");
} else {
todos.push(newTodo);
console.log(todos);
console.log('Successfully add Todo!');
}
}

Answer (score 0):

One first might come up with a definition of a valid todo item like "a string value" or even "a somehow non empty string value". Then one might think about writing an expression that validates this item. This validation also is the clause of whether to log a warning or to finally push the valid item to the todo list.

```js
function validateAndAddTodo(todoList, todoItem) {
  if (
    (typeof todoItem === 'string') // should be a string value
    && (todoItem.trim() !== '') // should be somehow non-empty
  ) {
    todoList.push(todoItem);
  } else {
    console.warn('you need to add a todo sir!');
  }
}

const todos = [];

validateAndAddTodo(todos);
validateAndAddTodo(todos, null);
validateAndAddTodo(todos, '');
validateAndAddTodo(todos, '      ');
validateAndAddTodo(todos, 'add another todo item');
validateAndAddTodo(todos, 'add yet another todo item');

console.info('todos : ', todos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```